# 'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with' when submitting a form via XHR

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, jquery-select2

I want a user to be able to select from an existing list of options. If the option is not within the ones already in the database, though, they need to be able to add a new item, while remaining on the main form, because after having added the new item they need to be able to save the main form

I was using the JQuery library select2, which allows a tags:True option, thanks to which users can add a new item to a list if not present. Nevertheless, Django validates that field and if it finds an item which is not in the database is raises an error. My initial plan was that of capturing the new value in the view and then (saving first the form with commit=False), if it was not in the database, save it. But this is not doable without forcing Django not to validate the field, which I haven't managed to do.

Another option, which I'm currently investigating, is that of adding a modal pop-up containing the sub-form. Of course I'd like to avoid opening the sub-form in another page, which would work but would be quite non-user-friendly.

models.py:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    venue_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class performanceOfCompositionNoDb(models.Model):

    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class VenueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = ['venue_name']
```

views.py:

```
def composition_edit_view(request, id=id):
    form_composition = CompositionForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
    form_venue = VenueForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST" and form_composition.is_valid():
    form_composition.save()

    context = {

        'form_composition': form_composition,
        'form_venue': form_venue
[...]

def venue_add_view(request):

    form_venue = VenueForm(request.POST or None)

    if form_venue.is_valid():
        form_venue.save()

    context = {
        'form_venue': form_venue,
    }

    return render(request, "venue-add.html", context)
```

my template.html:

```
{% include '../venue-add.html'%}
<form id="compositionForm" action='.' enctype="multipart/form-data" method='POST'>

{{form_composition}}

<p><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-open="addvenueModal">Add new venue</a></p>

<input class="button" type='submit' id='save' value='Save' />

</form>
```

venue-add.html:

```
<div class="reveal" id="addvenueModal" data-reveal>
<form action='.' enctype="multipart/form-data" method='POST'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">

    {{ form_venue }}

</div>
    <input class="button" type='submit' value='Save' />

    </div>
</form>

</div>
```

I'm expecting to open the venue-add form when I click on the 'Add new venue' button, which happens. With the modal open and the new text input, I then click the 'submit' button of the modal. At that point I get a 'Validation error - ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']'. I have other formsets in the main template, and it all works correctly if I don't add a new venue.

How can I solve this? Also, if there's a way of using the select2 library and add a new venue in a more dynamic way, do let me know! Thanks.

**Testing with XHR**

Using XHR gives the same `['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']` error in the response:

```
<div class="reveal" id="addVenue" data-reveal>
<form id="addVenueForm" action='.' onsubmit="addVenue(this); return false;" enctype="multipart/form-data" method='POST'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">

    {{ form_venue }}

</div>
    <input class="button" type='submit' value='Save' />

    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">   "use strict";

function addVenue (oFormElement) {

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = new FormData(oFormElement)

oReq.onload = {}
oReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (oReq.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    var result = oReq.responseText;}
}

oReq.open("post", oFormElement.action, true);
oReq.send(data);

} </script>
```

As I said, I *do* have formsets (working correctly) in the main form from which I'm launching this modal. This modal doesn't contain any formset though, it's a simple one-field form, with its own csrf token.

**Edit 2**

OK, so upon further investigating I've found that the error springs from

```
return render(request, "compositions/composition_edit.html", context)
```

in the view.py. In other words, when I hit 'submit' in the modal, for some reason the 'submit' of the main form kicks in also, thus generating issues. How can I isolate the 'submit' of the modal and get the 'submit' of the main form not to kick in unless explicitly clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the `action` of the modal form to the address I mapped in my urls.py (`action='/venue-add/'`) for that form. That solved the issue.

Now, the newly-added items are not displayed in the main form unless I refresh the page, no matter ho many times I destroy/empty/repopulate the select2() dropdown list. I think this has to do with the fact that the data to the venue dropdown list is sent by the view at the loading of the main form, and that the context remains the same no matter what updates to the database have been made after the page loading.

For the above reason I'm investigating using an API on my own application and GET and POST data via an AJAX call, which still gives me issue. I'm opening another question for that though.